# how to animate a bee swarm

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes, particles, simulation-nodes

i wish to simulate a swarm of bees where the bees are all gathered on their hive at first, then a rock is thrown at their hive, making the whole swarm agitated and chaotic all of a sudden. The rock is secondary. the main focus is the bee swarm and their motions.

Comment: Hello, I suggest you look into the boid system, although it feels like a disguised job offer for free which is not suited for this site. What have you done so far and where exactly do you have trouble making it work ?

Comment: I've never used them but it sounds like an ideal use for Blender's [Boids](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/particles/emitter/physics/boids.html). There's a tutorial about using them [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J3TUPYVsxow). It's done in Blender 2.9, but the settings seem to be the same in the latest version.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Create your hive and bee, give a *Emitter* particle system to the hive with the bee as object, enable *Physics Type > Boids* and *Boid Brain > Separate* and *Goal* with the hive as goal *Object*, so that the bees are both agitated and attracted to the hive:

[image]

Create a *Force Field > Turbulence*, keyframe its *Strength*, make it begin low and suddenly increase it:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: its working thanks a lot for your guidance